# Connecting Forms in Intellij IDEA Java, swing

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I am making application, using `IDEA` Forms. I want to have different forms. First for login, then for displaying information from database after login. I created two different forms. First one: `MenuMain` and second `AdminForm`. After clicking a login button in MenuMain I want to open AdminForm, I tried with `setContentPane` and passing main panel from AdminForm, but it does not work. How to solve this?

```
public class MenuMainForm extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private JPanel panel1;
private JTextPane logowanieText;
private JTextField userField;
private JTextField passField;
private JButton logowanieButton;
 public MenuMainForm(){

    logowanieButton.addActionListener(this);
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    AdminForm adminForm = new AdminForm();
    this.setContentPane(adminForm);
}

public static void main( String[] args){
JFrame menuFrame = new JFrame("Kawiarnia");
    menuFrame.setContentPane(new MenuMainForm().panel1);
    menuFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    menuFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    menuFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

And the AdminForm Code:

```
public class AdminForm extends JPanel{
private JPanel adminPanel;
private JButton infoKawiarniaButton;
private JTable tabelaInfo;
private static String QUERY_INFO = "SELECT  * FROM NATALIAGAZDA.KAWIARNIE ";


public AdminForm() {
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tabelaInfo.getModel();
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"Atrybut", "Wartosc"});
public JPanel getAdminPanel() {
    return adminPanel;
}
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: So this is the main from main in  MenuMainForm:JFrame menuFrame = new JFrame("Kawiarnia");
        menuFrame.setContentPane(new MenuMainForm().panel1);
        menuFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        menuFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        menuFrame.setVisible(true);

Comment: Don't paste it in the comments please. Edit the question and include the code using the code tool.

Comment: Ok, got it:) Sorry my first post on slack, Ididnt added all code concerning Databasse, just the forms gui part.

Comment: Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).